# Excel VBA DO loop to scan range of dates and fill in missing dates

Tags: date, loops, excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a worksheet that has ~20,000 rows of data.  Each row has a Transaction Date in Column C.  Each worksheet will only include data from the previous month.  What I am trying to have happen, is to have a loop run through each date and make sure there are no missing dates, if there is a missing date, I need the loop to insert the missing date into a new row.  I have found this online and  have tried to customize it to my worksheet but cannot get it to work:

```
 Dim i As Long:  i = 1
 'Adds missing dates as new rows
 Do
 If Cells(i + 1, "C") > Cells(i, "C") + 1 Then
      Rows(i + 1).Insert xlShiftDown
      Cells(i + 1, "C") = Cells(i, "C") + 1
 End If
 i = i + 1
 Loop Until Cells(i + 1, "C") = ""
```

I have a bunch of different macros that format the data into a table and then sort it by the transaction date.  I'm not sure if the table creates another issue or not but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Values on column C are unique? i.e. each row has a different date? Are talking about business days or week days?

Comment: No, the values in C are not Unique, there are a lot of repeated dates.  They only span 31 days max so each date has hundreds/thousands of records.  They are days of the week (all 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with data that looks like this:

[image]

---

Run this code to loop through the dates bottom up and insert missing rows.

```
Sub insertMissingDate()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wks.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

    'Work bottom up since we are inserting new rows
    For i = lastRow To 3 Step -1
        curcell = wks.Cells(i, 3).Value
        prevcell = wks.Cells(i - 1, 3).Value

        'Using a loop here allows us to bridge a gap of multiple missing dates
        Do Until curcell - 1 = prevcell Or curcell = prevcell
            'Insert new row
            wks.Rows(i).Insert xlShiftDown

            'Insert missing date into new row
            curcell = wks.Cells(i + 1, 3) - 1
            wks.Cells(i, 3).Value = curcell
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the work from the bottom when inserting. Always a good thing to remember

Comment: This looks great.  As I read through it, it appears that it is comparing each cell to the previous one, what will happen when the previous cell is the same as the current cell?  Many of the dates are repeated, hundreds/thousands of times?

Comment: That would create an infinite loop.  I've updated the answer to include and `OR` statement checking if the dates are equal.  As long as the dates are sorted this should do the trick.

Comment: This: `Do Until curcell - 1 <= prevcell` would also solve that problem instead of using `OR`

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you.  I have tested it with several different months and ways and it works almost perfectly.  The only question I have is this: if the last day of the month is missing, it doesn't fill it in.  Is there anyway that it can insert that too?

Comment: That would be more difficult since each month has different number of days.  I'd recommend posting that as a new question after you've searched a bit for existing solutions.  I myself haven't tried something like that before.  Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

A note to anyone using this code- you have to have your date formatted so that in single digit months, (i.e. January- example "1/1/17") you have a zero in front of the month, making it two digit (i.e. 01/1/17). The code will not work unless you do this. There is a data type under "more data formats" on the home page of excel that will include zeros in front of a single digit month. Thanks for the code, it's helping me tremendously!